# Capture prompt from stdout

Tags: rust, common-lisp, sbcl

I am starting a `Command`, and writing to its `stdin`  and reading its `stdout`, to basically pipe it into another terminal (`xterm.js`)
The command in case is long running and interactive (it's a Lisp REPL).
My code works, but I have one problem: How can I know if the Command is prompting for input instead of just printing out?

If I read `>`  without a newline at the end from the command's `stdout`, its probably the process prompting the user for input. But it could also be that its a long running evaluation, that just happens to print `>`  in the middle, but is not finished yet. How can I distinguish these cases?

```
    // using the os_pipe crate to create a new pipe with both, stdout and stderr,
    // to capture both, in correct order
    let (reader, writer_out) = os_pipe::pipe().unwrap();
    let writer_err = writer_out.try_clone().unwrap();
  
    let mut c = Command::new("path/to/sbcl");
    let mut child = 
        c
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(writer_out)
        .stderr(writer_err)
        .spawn()
        .expect("command failed to start");
    
    let (sender, receiver) = bounded::<String>(0);

    let mut f = BufReader::new(reader);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        
        let mut buf = String::new();
        // using the utf8_chars crate to iterate over chars of the bufreader
        for c in f.chars().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
            buf.push(c);
            if c == '\n' {
                sender.send(buf.clone()).expect("Failed to send.");
                buf.clear();
            } 
            // matches "> " or similar
            // if a "> " was sent without newline, I still want to capture it 
            else if RE_PROMPT.is_match(&buf) {
                sender.send(buf.clone()).expect("Failed to send.");
                buf.clear();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to distinguish the cases. An actual interactive user of the REPL also wouldn't be able to. A REPL generally isn't built for this purpose.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to wait for a prompt to send the next input. You can simply send it immediately, and the pipe will buffer it until it's read by the REPL. if the buffer is full, writing to stdin of the REPL will block.

Comment: That's a bummer. An actual interactive user would be able to distinguish though, at least for this REPL, if I run a function in the REPL that prints out "> ", sleeps for 10 seconds, then prints "finished", the "> " has a blinking cursor after it, but does not show any input if I type (the input shows up all at once when the function has finished). So as a user I would indeed recognize that the function is still running.

Comment: That's ather surprising behaviour. What OS are you on? I just tried this on Linux, and if I type during a `(sleep 10)`, the input is visible immediately.

Comment: It's also still rather unclear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you want to embed a Lisp interpreter in your Rust program, you should load it as a library in some way. Apparently, ECL is specifically designed for this purpose, but [SBCL also supports embedding](https://mstmetent.blogspot.com/2022/04/using-lisp-libraries-from-other.html).

Comment: I'm on Windows right now. 
The test I'm running is `(defun test () (format t "* ") (finish-output) (sleep 10) (format t "finished."))`. It prints `* `, lets me write immediately, but only shows my input after the sleep finished. Tested in cmd and powershell. (I did my above code with `> ` for clarity, but actually `* ` is the prompt in SBCL).

What I am trying to achieve: I am coding a CL editor, web-based, in which I run [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/), which I want to connect to a running SBCL instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that no mechanism based on merely inspecting what a program prints can reliably tell if it has just printed a prompt and is now waiting for input: whatever it is looking for can simply be printed by the program to fool it.

The only trick you could possibly do is to somehow know then whatever is on the other end of the pipe is trying to read from it, which would indicate that it is expecting input and thus what it just printed might be a prompt.  It may be that you can do that with pseudoterminals on *nix.  Even this is not completely reliable.

However the right way to do this is not to screen-scrape output at all: it's to build a protocol whereby the system you are talking to *tells* you when it has done whatever you asked and is waiting for you to ask it.  That is what swank does, for instance.